# How to Override Popup Block Browser Setting in jQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a button that if clicked checks login credentials, if valid credentials provided a new window should open along with dynamic framing url passed to that window. If I didn't made any popup block setting in browser then it works. However if popup is blocked then it has to over ride that setting and has to open.

I wrote an ajax success call in jQuery

```
var newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', "top=100, left=300,width=1024, height=640");
newWindow.focus();
if (!newWindow || newWindow.closed || typeof newWindow == 'undefined' || typeof newWindow.closed == 'undefined') {

// here it should override setting
}
```

or else help me out how to archive this this link functionality
http://vegas.williamhill.com/

If I click on play now it will open new popup if I made browser settings and ask for login then it will load playGame..

Comment: it wouldn't be very secure, if a javascript could override browsersettings for opening/allowing popup's...

Comment: Can You please suggest then how to do in MVC4 in asp.net?

Comment: Unless you're preparing to hack somebody's system you wouldn't wanna do this. I for example, always disable pop-up by default. And I would never prefer anyone changing my setting without my permission. Say, for ex. if some stranger enters your house and start making some changes, be it good or bad won't you raise an exception?? The preferred way is to tell the user to kindly allow pop-ups for your site. Next it's up to them.

Comment: I agree with your words even i am doing same now. if that popup is blocked i showing message like to change setting. But i am surprise to see in this link  [http://vegas.williamhill.com/](http://vegas.williamhill.com/) in this how they achieved the same even my browser setting is blocked popup then??